# IE7 jquery.post do not trigger

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, internet-explorer-7

I am currently Using this script to post the form to avoid refresh submits.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        var url = "http://example.com/process.php"; // the script that handles the form input.
        $.post(url, {
            name: $("input[name='name']").val(),
            type: $("select[name='type'] option:selected").text(),
            address: $("input[name='address']").val(),
            city: $("input[name='city']").val(),
            state: $("select[name='state'] option:selected").text(),
            zip: $("input[name='zip']").val(),
            phone: $("input[name='phone']").val(),
            email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
            sig: $("input[name='sig']").val(),
            date: $(".date1").datepicker("getDate"),
            lic_numb: $("input[name='lic_numb']").val(),
            lic_date: $(".date2").datepicker("getDate"),
            code: ')@tEH4s'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
            $('input').val('');
            $('#form1').css("height", "0");
        });
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

This works fine in all other browsers such as chrome and firefox, but I keep getting reports saying this does not trigger any action in ie7.

Any idea on syntax issue that caused this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you trigger the click from an onclick event from some button use:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```